# In a 2d array, find the mean of each column but ignore values of 0,

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around $.map(). I am trying to find the mean of each column in a 2d array but ignore a value of 0 when it comes to generating that mean.

Example:

```
var numbers = [[2,2,1],
               [3,3,2],
               [2,0,5],
               [2,4,5]]
```

the result of the above would be [2.25, 3, 3.5]. Notice to find the mean of index[1] or 2,3,0,4 = 9 would be 9/3 because I want to ignore the 0 value.

so far I have figured out:

```
var mean = numbers.map(function(row, i) {
  return numbers.map(function(row) {
    return row[i];
    });
```

this I believe gets me the appropriate columns of the 2d arrays but them I'm stuck. Thanks for your help. I would also like to invoke the math.mean() method.

Comment: Can we assume that length of all the arrays will be same, always! Like 3 Here..

Comment: Yes the length of the arrays will always be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and clear vanilla JS code:

```
var numbers = [
    [2, 2, 1],
    [3, 3, 2],
    [2, 0, 5],
    [2, 4, 5]
]

var l = numbers[0].length;
var w = numbers.length;
var mean = [];
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    var elem = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < w; j++) {
        sum += numbers[j][i];
        elem = elem + (numbers[j][i] == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    }
    mean.push(sum / elem);
}
console.log(mean);
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8wvg38a/)

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close already. You can use a combination of [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var numbers = [[2,2,1],
               [3,3,2],
               [2,0,5],
               [2,4,5]];

function means(arr) {
   return arr[0].map(function(item, index) {
     var len = arr.length;
     var sum = arr.reduce(function(a, b, i) {
         if(b[index] === 0) {
             len--;
         }
         return a + b[index];
     }, 0);
     return sum / len;
   });
 }

 means(numbers);
```

Comment: Even nicer with ES6: `arr.map(item => item.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) / item.length)`

Comment: Why `arr.slice()` and `arr[0]`? Are you trying to avoid altering the original array (`Array.prototype.map` doesn't do that anyway)?

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, I totally forgot that. Slicing is removed. I need `arr[0]` to get the total length of the inner arrays.